# Can not install scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing scikit-learn**

1. Install the version of scikit-learn provided by your operating system or Python distribution. This is the quickest option for those who have operating systems that distribute scikit-learn.
2. Install an official release. ...
3. Install the latest development version.

Or just install Anaconda Navigator from https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual